# I have a dataset on which I want to do Phrase extraction using NLP but I am unable to do so?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence, nltk, word2vec

How can I extract a phrase from a sentence using a dataset which has some set of the sentence and corresponding label in the form of

```
Sentence1:I want to play cricket 
Label1: play cricket

Sentence2: Need to wash my clothes
Label2: wash clothes
```

I have tried using chunking with nltk but I am not able to use training data along with the chunks.

Comment: Why are the labels you've provided the "right" phrases to extract from the given sentences? (What's the ultimate goal, or guiding standard?)

Comment: @gojomo The ultimate goal is to extract a reminder phrase out of a sentence. For example: "Please remind me to go to gym" --> "go to gym"

Answer (score 1):

The "reminder paraphrases" you describe don't map exactly to other kinds of "phrases" with explicit software support.

For example, the gensim `Phrases` module uses a purely statistical approach to discover neighboring word-pairings that are so common, relative to the base rates of each word individually, that they might usefully be considered a combined unit. It might turn certain entities into phrases (eg: "New York" -> "New_York"), or repeated idioms (eg: "slacking off" -> "slacking_off"). But it'd only be neighboring-runs-of-words, and not the sort of contextual paraphrase you're seeking.

Similarly, libraries which are suitably grammar-aware to mark-up logical parts-of-speech (and inter-dependencies) also tend to simply group and label existing phrases in the text – not create simplified, imperative summaries like you desire.

Still, such libraries' output might help you work up your own rules-of-thumb. For example, it appears in your examples so far, your desired "reminder paraphrase" is always one verb and one noun (that verb's object). So after using part-of-speech tagging (as from NLTK or SpaCy), choosing the *last* verb (perhaps also preferring verbs in present/imperative tense), and the *following* noun-phrase (perhaps stripped of other modifiers/prepositions) may do most of what you need.

Of course, more complicated examples would need better heuristics. And if the full range of texts you need to work on is very varied, finding a general approach might require many more (hundreds/thousands) of positive training examples: what *you* think the best paraphrase is, given certain texts. Then, you could consider a number of machine-learning methods that might be able to pick the right ~2 words from larger texts.

Researching published work for "paraphrasing", rather than just "phrase extraction", might also guide you to ideas, but I unfortunately don't know any ready-to-use paraphrasing libraries.

Comment: How can I choose the best grammar by using the training dataset which have the sentences and extracted paraphrases.

Comment: What do you mean by "best grammar"? With enough examples, won't certain patterns be evident, and/or exceptions/difficult cases? Right now, you've only shown 3 examples, and for those, the simple rule "take the last 2 or 3 words, but don't start with 'to'" works fine. (Part-of-speech tagging isn't even yet a needed hint!) You'd need many more examples, including hard examples, to have an idea if more complicated analysis is required.

Comment: I have a dataset of 10,000 sentences and there corresponding extracted phrases in the form of a tsv file. And I want to make a model that can Improve itself on that data.

Comment: How many of the 10,000 examples does the simple rule I suggested above – "take the last 2 or 3 words, but don't start with 'to'" – work on? Of those that it doesn't work on, can they be cleanly distinguished from the ones where it does work, and does some other simple rule work? Are all 10,000 examples just using some subset of words in the original, in the original order? (Then your generic, learnable rule might be of the form, "for sentence S and word-in-sentence W, should W be in the paraphrase? (yes/no)" – a binary classification problem.)